# Drag an element over another in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

I am trying to drag and drop an element over another but I am not able to do so. I am trying to perform the above operation on http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop

This is my code

```
we1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='column-a']"));
we2=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='column-b']"));
action.clickAndHold(we1);
action.moveToElement(we2, 450, 250);
Thread.sleep(3000);
action.release().build().perform();
```

Instead of `action.moveToElement(we2,450,250)` I have even tried using `action.moveToElement(we2)` and `action.moveByOffset(450,250)`.

I even tried to perform this operation using Robot class.

```
robot.mouseMove(230, 170);  
Thread.sleep(3000);
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
robot.mouseMove(450, 200);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
```

Nothing happens in any of the above code. No error or exception is thrown and Code execution gets completed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of effort (hit & try :) ) I was able to find a solution for my problem. It is working fine for the site I mentioned as well as for other sites also where drag and drop functionality is present. Here is the solution:

```
        we1CenterX=we1Points.x+we1Dimensions.width/2;
        we1CenterY=we1Points.y+we1Dimensions.height/2;
        we2CenterX=we2Points.x+we2Dimensions.width/2;
        we2CenterY=we2Points.y+we2Dimensions.height/2;
        robot.mouseMove(we1CenterX, we1CenterY);

        waitForMe(1); //custom wait

        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        waitForMe(1);
        robot.mouseMove(we2CenterX, we2CenterY);
        waitForMe(1);

        robot.mouseMove(we2CenterX+100, we2CenterY-70); 
       /*Moving the cursor over the element before releasing 
         the mouse button solved my problem*/

        waitForMe(1);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);

        waitForMe(1);
```